# How to return the correct fields in Rails API?

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have these two tables - User, Accounts. 
User contains an authentication key, 
Accounts contains the list of accounts.

I am trying to get the list of accounts for the user if the authentication key is correct.

So in the controller I have -

```
def show
  @user = User.where(authentication_token: params[:authentication_token])
  render json: @user.as_json(
           only: [:email, :id, :authentication_token]
         ),
         status: :created
end
```

This would just return the user details. How can i edit it so it first checks if the user exists with that Authentication_token, and then uses the UserID, in the accounts table to get the list of accounts ?

Comment: `@user.accounts` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear: What is the desired behaviour if the `authentication_token` is **not** correct? Raise an exception? Redirect somewhere? Display a flash message? ...

You could, for example, do something like this:

```
def show
  if authenticated_user
    render json: authenticated_user.accounts.as_json(
             only: [:id, :foo, :bar]
           ),
           status: :ok
  else
    render json: { errors: { authentication_token: 'Invalid' } },
           status: :unauthorized
  end
end

private

def authenticated_user
  @authenticated_user ||= User.find_by(
    authentication_token: params[:authentication_token]
  )
end
```

Comment: I keep getting undefined method `accounts' while doing this. The accounts table exists and the authenticated_user is correct too.

Comment: Does the user `have_many` accounts? That's the assumption I made, but you didn't clarify this in your original post.